# Java class constants

Tags: java

I'd like to define a few public class constant-like variables for a class I also create an instance of.

In my class Response I've defined a few responseCodes which I'd like to use as constants all over the application.

Please don't worry about the sense of this code, this is just a copy and paste of snippets to show how I am trying to use the class constants.

My IntelliJ doesn't complain about this syntax at all, but when I am trying to build the code I get

```
Filter.java:[84,36] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable BR_PARTIALLY_OK
```

My sample class with consts

```
package xx.xx.xxxxx.connector;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Response {
    public static final int BR_OK                       = 200;
    public static final int BR_PARTIALLY_OK             = 250;
    public static final int BR_NOT_AUTHORIZED           = 401;
    public static final int BR_REQUEST_TIMEOUT          = 408;
    public static final int BR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED          = 501;
    public static final int BR_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE      = 503;

    private Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    private String body = null;

    public void addHeader(String key, List<String> value) {
        this.headers.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }
}
```

Desired example use in another class

```
package xx.xx.xxxxx.filter; // other package, other maven artifact but depends response package
import xx.xx.xxxxx.connector.Response;

public class Filter {
    public int doFilter(Service service) {
        Response myResponse = service.post(..);
        return Response.BR_PARTIALLY_OK;
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
import static xxx.xxx.Response.*
```

or

```
import static xxx.xxx.Response.BR_PARTIALLY_OK;
```

and use

```
return BR_PARTIALLY_OK
```

same "cannot find symbol" error already on the import

I've seen the interface and const class examples but I'd like to know why this example doesn't work

EDIT:
Maybe the problem is that the class is defined in a dependent artifact?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>xxx.xxxxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>used the Response.BR_PARTIALLY_OK constant here</groupId>
    <artifactId>filter</artifactId>
    <version>${connector.filter.version}</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>defined the Response class in this artifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>component</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.openutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>openutils-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>magnolia.public</id>
            <url>http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you get the "cannot find symbol" inside of IntelliJ or in a separate build?

Comment: You can use static variables by Classname.staticvariable. You need not import. Static variables are available for the entire application.

Comment: I've used maven compile within Intellij

Comment: Make sure the response class exists in the generated war

Comment: use Enums to declare constants.

Comment: Sounds like IntelliJ places something on the Classpath that Maven does not put there by itself.

Comment: Do you have the "same" class under same package more than once in the classpath? (for example this happens easy when you have to different versions of the same lib in the classpath) Then it may happend that a different class is loaded than you would expect to be loaded.

Comment: Definitely not code-related, the problem is with the build process.

Comment: Suppose you could try Ctrl + Alt + O for organise the imports

Comment: tried CTRL+ALT+O (cool feature, thx :)), maven clean, switching maven output level to debug - no additional info, project refresh, dont have the class several times. I don't see the problem

Comment: Maybe you can show the pom.xml?

Comment: (parent) pom.xml posted above. maybe the problem occurs because class Response is not in the same but in a dependent artifact as Filter is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thank you all for the time you spent on this. The problem indeed was build-related. Instead of rebuilding the whole project I just rebuilt one of the artifacts (by accident) this caused the problem because the const definitions where in the other artifact which was never rebuilt after adding the constants

building the parent scope solved this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I find the error message a bit off.

"variable BR_PARTIALLY_OK"

Variable? That would make me assume that the code does not contain 'Response.BR_PARTIALLY_OK" but only "BR_PARTIALLY_OK".

Comment: response.setStatus( Response.BR_EXCEPTION ); [INFO] Compilation failure [..] Filter.java:[83,51] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable BR_EXCEPTION
location: class xxx.xxx.Response